# Computing a multi-index sum in a Tensorflow loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I am experimenting with optimising a neural network using a loss function that is equivalent to the [concordance index](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/145566/how-to-calculate-area-under-the-curve-auc-or-the-c-statistic-by-hand) (c-index). The loss function I would like to use is (latex equation in link)

[∑*{i=0}^N ∑*{j=i}^N \sigma (  (y_i - y_j)(y'_i - y'_j ) )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWbWS.png)

where y' is the vector of predictions and y is the vector of labels in a batch of size N, and \sigma is the sigmoid function. I would like to be able to implement this in TensorFlow but I can't find a way to express the two-index sum.

I have tried rearranging the equation into a different form that can be expressed in terms of TensorFlow and Keras primitives but with no success. I am using Keras, so Keras or TensorFlow implementations would both be useable.

The Python code is

```
from itertools import permutations, combinations
a = np.arange(4)
a = a*100

def loss_ci(y_true, y_pred):
summ = 0.
total=0
for i in range(len(y_true)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(y_true)):
        summ += 1/(1+np.exp(-(y_true[i]-y_true[j]) * (y_pred[i]-y_pred[j])))
        total+=1
return (summ)/total

print("y_true\t\ty_pred\t\tc-index\tloss")
for c in permutations(a,3):
for d in combinations(a,3):
    print(c, d, "\t{:.4f}".format(ci(c, d)), "\t{:.4f}".format(loss_ci(c, d)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loss can be calculated using tensor flow as shown in the code below:

```
from itertools import permutations, combinations
a = np.arange(4)
a = a*100

def loss_ci(y_true, y_pred):
summ = 0.
total=0
for i in range(len(y_true)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(y_true)):
        summ += 1/(1+np.exp(-(y_true[i]-y_true[j]) * (y_pred[i]-y_pred[j])))


return (summ)

def tf_loss_ci(y_true, y_pred):
  Y = tf.constant(y_true)
  _Y = tf.constant(y_pred)
  S = tf.sigmoid(tf.multiply((Y[tf.newaxis,:]-Y[:,tf.newaxis]),(_Y[tf.newaxis,:]-_Y[:,tf.newaxis])))
  S = tf.reduce_sum(tf.matrix_set_diag(S,tf.zeros_like(Y))) / 2
  sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
  tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
  return S.eval()

print("y_true\t\ty_pred\t\ttensorloss\tloss")
for c in permutations(a,3):
  for d in combinations(a,3):
    print(c, d, "\t{:.4f}".format(tf_loss_ci(np.asarray(c, np.float32), np.array(d, np.float32))), "\t{:.4f}".format(loss_ci(c, d)))
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't implement the sigmoid fuction. I've edited the question to include the numpy version of the loss function. (Dividing by total isn't necessary but shows how the loss is equivalent to the c-index.)

Comment: My mistake.. made the changes